# Change first word in a sentence to uppercase

Tags: php, uppercase, toupper

I am looking to convert the first word of a sentence into uppercase but unsure how would I go about it. This is what I have so far:

```
$o = "";

  if((preg_match("/ibm/i", $m)) || (preg_match("/hpspecial/i", $m))) {

$o = strtoupper($m);

} else {

  $o = ucwords(strtolower($m));

}
```

I would like to use `uppercase` from the `hpspecial` ID where HP is the first part of the sentence to be capitalized, but this will uppercase the whole sentence. How do I only make HP of the sentence uppercase?

Comment: Can you give the full original sentence, and what you want it to be converted to? Your question is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 6):

you can dot his by [**`ucfirst`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)

> `ucfirst` — Make a string's first character uppercase

like

```
$foo = 'hello form world';
$foo = ucfirst($foo);
```

[**live output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dABr6U)

**edit:** to make it first word upper case you can do like

```
<?php
$foo = 'hello form world ';

$pieces = explode(" ", $foo);
$pieces[0] = strtoupper($pieces[0]);
$imp = implode(" ", $pieces);
echo $imp;
```

[**live result**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YYmcMV)

Comment: Thanks. But i would like the whole word of the SENTENCE to be uppercase, not the first letter. i know i have to use strtoupper but in my code i have provided it will convert the whole sentence of 'hpspecial' to uppercase, i just would like the FIRST word of the sentence upper

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$arr = explode(' ');
$arr[0] = strtoupper($arr[0]);

echo implode(' ' , $arr);
```

I don't know if there's a function built-in, but I think this should work?

Answer (score -1):

Seems that you don't really have a special pattern, why don't just use preg_replace?

```
$search = array('/ibm/i', '/hpspecial/i');
$replace = array('IBM', 'HPspecial');

$string = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

You have to do it like this anyway because you can't really difference HP from Special (at least with simple ways);

You can use the same approach using str_replace actually as you are not using complex patterns as far as I can see.

Sometimes the simplest solution is the best

Answer (score -1):

you can use custom function like

```
function uc_first_word ($string)
{
   $s = explode(' ', $string);   
   $s[0] = strtoupper($s[0]);   
   $s = implode(' ', $s);
   return $s;
}
```

$string = 'Hello world. This is a test.';
echo $s = uc_first_word ($string)

so output would be

```
HELLO world. This is a test
```

so first word before space will be as upper for whole sentence.